# How can I align the listview labels?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm learning how to use Kivy, and I would like to know how can I align the labels inside the listview I built.

The labels are centered by default, and I would like to align all the labels to the left.

My code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.listview import SimpleListAdapter
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        messages = ["a", "b"]
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        btn1 = Button(text='Hello')
        textinput = TextInput(text='Hello world', size_hint=(1, 0.1))
        messages.append("sd")
        simple_list_adapter = SimpleListAdapter(
            data=messages,
            cls=Label)
        simple_list_adapter.cls

        list_view = ListView(adapter=simple_list_adapter)
        layout.add_widget(list_view)
        layout.add_widget(textinput)
        return layout

TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to create a Label with that desired alignment

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.listview import SimpleListAdapter
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class LeftLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LeftLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#text-alignment-and-wrapping
        self.halign = "left"
        self.bind(size=self.setter("text_size"))


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        messages = ["a", "b"]
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        btn1 = Button(text="Hello")
        textinput = TextInput(text="Hello world", size_hint=(1, 0.1))
        messages.append("sd")
        simple_list_adapter = SimpleListAdapter(data=messages, cls=LeftLabel)
        list_view = ListView(adapter=simple_list_adapter)
        layout.add_widget(list_view)
        layout.add_widget(textinput)
        return layout


TestApp().run()
```

Since you are starting in kivy it is recommended that you learn RecycleView instead of ListView since the latter is [deprecated](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.listview.html):

> Deprecated since version 1.10.0: ListView has been deprecated, use RecycleView instead.